# Compose React app based on the value of a flag

Tags: reactjs, components, composition

**Problem Statement:**

I want to compose my react app to use a specific set of components based on the value of a flag.

For Eg:

I have an App component consisting of three components by default:

ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC.

```
<App> 
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    <ComponentC />
<App/>
```

Now, if my flag is equal to ShowC, the I want my App to render ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC.

If the flag is equal to ShowD, then instead of ComponentC I want to render ComponentD instead.

```
<App> 
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    <ComponentD />
<App/>
```

**Solution:**

I have used a config object that has the respective imports in as key-value pairs:

```
{
    showC: {
        pos1: ComponentA,
        pos2: ComponentB,
        pos3: ComponentC,
    },
    showD: {
        pos1: ComponentA,
        pos2: ComponentB,
        pos3: ComponentD,
    }
}
```

Now, in my main App.js:

```
render() {
    const {
        pos1: FirstComponent,
        pos2: SecondComponent,
        pos3: ThirdComponent
    } = config[<flag>];

    <App>
        <FirstComponent />
        <SecondComponent />
        <ThirdComponent />
    </App>
}
```

I have created a simple example on stackblitz illustrating this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-app-components-config?file=index.js

I want to understand if composing components in this way is considered an anti-pattern in React? Or if there is a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can create  a HOC which would decide what to render based on the flag

```
const DynamicComponent = ({type,children}) => (

  { // you can have any condition here.
    type === 'a'?
    children[0]:
    children[1]
  }

)
```

// your main component

```
render() {

    <App>
        <FirstComponent />
        <SecondComponent />
        <DynamicComponent type={config.type}> 
           <ThirdComponent />
           <FourthComponent />
        </DynamicComponent>
    </App>
}
```

you should always try to create a new HOC for any such composition, it follows functional programming composition pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This eg is a simplified version of a larger application that I am working on. In that app, I want the ability to customise/override any component that is a part of my main <App/> , not just the last component. So using this pattern, I'd need to wrap all my components in a HOC. Not sure how extendable that'll be if the flag based off which I'm driving the logic has 4/5 possible values instead of just 2.

Comment: i would suggest a HOC and pass all config to that HOC and based on your logic and render what u want. why HOC is usefull because you can pass components as props.  you can have any custom logic in your HOC. if the logic is complex use class components to simplify things. you really dont want to have the complex logic in the root.. you need to make multiple HOC's based on your requirement and render. @Pranita